# Need for Cloud Firestore Authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm making a contact tracing app that categorizes users on the basis of their phoneID and their real-time location. That been said, I have no authentication page and I am storing all this data on the cloud Firestore. My current security rules are like this =

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /sampleData/{anything=**}{
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
    match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, this works absolutely fine and I don't think that I have to change it in any way. Because I have a completely random user categorizing himself and his location and can't really access any other user's location because of every user's Random ID, I think that these security rules work fine.
Is there any necessity of changing them?
The Random ID is a combination of BuildType+BuildLength+Math.random+random characters that once created, is permanently stored in shared preferences.
Thank yOu !

Answer (score 1):

**Your rules currently allow anyone with an internet connection to read and write every single document.**  If you're OK with this, and all the surprises that come with it, including massive amounts of billing, or complete data loss, then there is no need to change anything.

If you don't want this, you should strongly look into using Firebase Auth to sign users in, and give each user read and write access to only the documents and collection they are allowed.

Comment: What if every time a user comes in he adds another document ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you are trying to figure out how to build security rules for a specific use case, I suggest explaining your situation in a new question, and show the rules you have tried that don't work the way you expect.

Comment: So basically, every time a new user is created, he creates a new collection with his location and address, so if I add authentication and specify a path, it would do no good because essentially every time a user creates an account a new collection and a new document is created.

Comment: So how can I add an authentication of collections and documents with the collections and documents changing every time the user changes his postion.

Comment: Thank you for being so responsive to this rookie!